# react-native-calendar-strip not scrolling like shown in the docs

Tags: react-native, expo, mobile-application, scrollable

```
<CalendarStrip
selectedDate={selectedDate}
onPressDate={handleDateSelected}
style={{ height: 150, paddingTop: 20, paddingBottom: 10 }}
calendarColor={'#FFFFFF'}
calendarHeaderStyle={{ color: '#000000' }}
dateNumberStyle={{ color: '#000000' }}
dateNameStyle={{ color: '#000000' }}
highlightDateNumberStyle={{ color: '#0b46a3' }}
highlightDateNameStyle={{ color: '#0b46a3' }}
iconContainer={{ flex: 0 }}
markedDatesStyle={{ borderRadius: 15, backgroundColor: '#0b46a3' }}
scrollable={true} // Set scrollable to true
scrollerPaging={true}
leftSelector={[]}
rightSelector={[]}
minDate={moment().subtract(1, 'years').format('YYYY-MM-DD')} // Set minimum date (1 year ago)
maxDate={moment().add(1, 'years').format('YYYY-MM-DD')} // Set maximum date (1 year from now)
/>
```

Here is my code but its not working like how its supposed to work in react native expo

i tried setting the scrollable= true but still its not working like whats shown in the docs